# How to validate email From: address with authenticated user (prevent sender/login mismatch) in dovecot submission server?

Tags: dovecot

Im looking for the same behavior as postfix [reject_sender_login_mismatch](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch), however i want dovecot to handle this.

Starting since version 2.3 Dovecot offers a [submission SMTP:587 server](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/submission_server/). I like this and it makes more logic to me, dovecot is already handling imap/pop3 services so why shouldn't you be able to send emails with the same service.

This must not be widely used because i can not find any information other than the very light documentation at the link above. Everything i find online explains how to have postfix talk to dovecot through "private/auth" to get user authentication to match against the From: address.

This is bonkers to me. Why bother having dovecot listen on port 587 if it has to send the email to postfix, for postfix to turn around and connect back to dovecot to get auth info to decide if the email matches? Dovecot should decide this before sending the email to postfix since it already has the connection, the user authentication, and list of valid emails.

Im running (CentOS8) `dovecot 2.3.8` and `postfix 3.3.1` with both talking to `sql` for user account info. Postfix is only listening on port 25 for incoming mail and dovecot is handling all things imap on ports 143, 993 and 587.

Does anyone know how to do this in dovecot or can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Most people do indeed use their existing SMTP server (in your case, postfix) to accept submissions. I haven't heard of anyone using dovecot for this, and I can't even think of a reason why one would want to.

Comment: Because dovecot add it, dovecot has its own SMTP submission server so you do not need to use postfix and makes more sense to me since dovcot is what handles IMAP services. The reason why, why not? Dovecot handles IMAP, and postfix has to talk to dovecot anyways to authenticate submission so makes more sense to me to let dovecot handle it from start to finish. Seems hacky the way most people do it now using postfix which then has to talk back to dovecot.

Comment: Adding more and more SMTP-related capabilities to dovecot sounds **more** *hacky* to me than the simple proxy adding *only* the IMAP-related capabilities while continuing to use the tried and tested postfix for everything else.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the Dovecot [Submission Server](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/submission_server/) documentation:

> **Note**
>
> Currently, the submission proxy is still pretty basic.

It does not have any of the advanced features Postfix has, nor even the capability to deliver the message on its own. It is merely a proxy that still requires a fully featured MTA, like Postfix.

*Submission* is not IMAP, but SMTP. Therefore, it is only natural that an SMTP server handles it. Just like with us humans, it is good to specialise on something, do it as good as possible, and ask help for other things. For the same reason, Postfix does not try and implement [SASL authentication](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) on its own:

> Postfix does not implement SASL itself, but instead uses existing
> implementations as building blocks. This means that some SASL-related
> configuration files will belong to Postfix, while other configuration
> files belong to the specific SASL implementation that Postfix will
> use. This document covers both the Postfix and non-Postfix
> configuration.
>
> NOTE: People who go to the trouble of installing Postfix may have the
> expectation that Postfix is more secure than some other mailers. The
> Cyrus SASL library contains a lot of code. With this, Postfix becomes
> as secure as other mail systems that use the Cyrus SASL library.
> Dovecot provides an alternative that may be worth considering.

TL;DR: It is not currently possible and might never be. Just use the Postfix for submission like everybody else.